# typeorm foreign Key to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I have three entities. How can I make the relationship based on document `type` column?

```js
export class BuyInvoice {
 // ...columns
}
```

```js
export class SellInvoice {
 // ...columns
}
```

```js
export class AccountingDocument {
  //...other columns

  @Column('enum', { enum: DocumentType })
  type: DocumentType;

  @ManyToOne(() => BuyInvoice) // OR SellInvoice based on type column
  invoice: BuyInvoice; // OR SellInvoice based on type column
}
```

I don't want to make two nullable relationships, because I have the same problem elsewhere with more than 5 types and just one of them is not null.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation as you. I defined it my relations like this : 
`@ManyToOne(() => Package || Shipment, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
 @JoinColumn({
  referencedColumnName: "package_id" || "shipment_id"
 })
 entityId?: Package | Shipment;`
but it doesn't work neither

Comment: Hey did you get solution for this ?

Comment: @YuvrajAgarkar there is a concept called polymorphism. I could not find any solution that I like.

Comment: polymorphism relating to OOP?, share a link if you have .. thanks